# hook_views_pre_render -> how to access variables

Tags: views

I have a view of teasers, and would like to check the status of each node. 
Using hook_views_pre_render (in the template.php file of the theme), I can access:

```
$view->style_plugin->row_plugin
```

Which gives me the output below (only first few lines printed, using debug):

```
entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view::__set_state(array(
 'entity_type' => 'node',
 'entities' => 
 array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'vid' => '19',
     'uid' => '1',
     'title' => 'My Node Title',
     'log' => '',
     'status' => '0',
     'comment' => '1',
     'promote' => '0',
```

However, I can't figure out how to access the status variable.

```
debug($view->style_plugin->row_plugin->entities());
```

produces a white screen, any variation that I tried either returned NULL or a white screen.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `row_plugin` appears to be an array, not an object. Have you tried `$view->style_plugin->row_plugin['entities']`?

Comment: `$view->style_plugin->row_plugin` isn't an array: It's an instance of the `entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view` class. What shown in the question is the output of `var_dump()` for an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) if you haven't already and use `dpm($view);` to see the structure of the view, then you can drill down to the part of the variable that you wish to inspect.

The devel module will print the result of your `dpm()` in the message area as long as there are no syntax errors in your module crashing the site.

I have found `drush cc all` [(Linux command line tool)](http://drush.ws/) to be useful in finding syntax errors though I suspect there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

`entities` isn't a method, so you cannot use `$view->style_plugin->row_plugin->entities()`.

What shown in the question is the output of `var_dump()` for the instance of a class, in this case [`entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/entity/views--plugins--entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view.inc/class/entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view/7). The `$entities` property is protected, so it cannot be directly accessed from outside the class.

```php
class entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view extends views_plugin_row {

  protected $entity_type, $entities;

  // …

}
```

[`entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view::get_value()`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/entity/views--plugins--entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view.inc/function/entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view%3A%3Aget_value/7) returns values from that property. More exactly, it returns the entity for the view row associated with that class instance.

In your case, you should use `$view->style_plugin->row_plugin->get_value(NULL)`.